# Implementing TCP keep alive at the application level

Tags: tcp, batch-processing, firewall, keep-alive

We have a shell script setup on one Unix box (A) that remotely calls a web service deployed on another box (B). On A we just have the scripts, configurations and the Jar file needed for the classpath.

After the batch job is kicked off, the control is passed over from A to B for the transactions to happen on B. Usually the processing is finished on B in less than an hour, but in some cases (when we receive larger data for processing) the process continues for more than an hour. In those cases the firewall tears down the connection between the 2 hosts after an inactivity of 1 hour. Thus, the control is never returned back from B to A and we are not notified that the batch job has ended.

To tackle this, our network team has suggested to implement keep-alives at the application level.

My question is - where should I implement those and how? Will that be in the web service code or some parameters passed from the shell script or something else? Tried to google around but could not find much.

Answer (score 0):

You basically send an application level message and wait for a response to it. That is, your applications must support sending, receiving and replying to those heart-beat messages. See [FIX Heartbeat message](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/5.0/msgType_0_0.html) for example:

> The Heartbeat monitors the status of the communication link and identifies when the last of a string of messages was not received.
>
> When either end of a FIX connection has not sent any data for [HeartBtInt] seconds, it will transmit a Heartbeat message. When either end of the connection has not received any data for (HeartBtInt + "some reasonable transmission time") seconds, it will transmit a Test Request message. If there is still no Heartbeat message received after (HeartBtInt + "some reasonable transmission time") seconds then the connection should be considered lost and corrective action be initiated....

Additionally, the message you send should include a local timestamp and the reply to this message should contain that same timestamp. This allows you to measure the application-to-application round-trip time.

Also, some NAT's close your TCP connection after N minutes of inactivity (e.g. after 30 minutes). Sending heart-beat messages allows you to keep a connection up for as long as required.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am more of looking from an implementation perspective. Can we set up those heartbeats from the shell scripts? If yes, how? Sorry am not a pro at scripting.